# Getting Node.io to work through a proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, node.io

I'm trying to use node.io (web scraping module) through a proxy. I know it has untested support for proxies built in, but I cannot get it to work. Does anyone know how to get it working?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you add more information to your question? Your program is connecting to the internet via a proxy and this is messing things up?

Comment: node.io is deprecated, you should use a more recent alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure npm to make node to use a proxy server;

> npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
>   npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080'

Comment: You should see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586902/node-js-global-proxy-setting also.