# Node.js global proxy setting

Tags: node.js, proxy

I was working in a corporate network behind a proxy server. In my code I can set the proxy by using the approach mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-http-client).

But the problem is that most of the 3rd party modules do not have proxy setting and I cannot modify their code to add the proxy. Also, my code might be used in a direct connection environment which means I cannot hard-code my proxy setting in code.

I know NPM has a global setting for proxy which is

```sh
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

But I didn't find any config similar in Node.js.

Does Node.js support global proxy setting so that I don't need to change all codes and switch on and off easily?

Comment: As of Node.js v12, you can use https://github.com/gajus/global-agent.

Answer (score 32):

Unfortunately, it seems that proxy information must be set on each call to `http.request`. Node does not include a mechanism for global proxy settings.

The [`global-tunnel-ng` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-tunnel-ng) on NPM appears to handle this, however:

```
var globalTunnel = require('global-tunnel-ng');

globalTunnel.initialize({
  host: '10.0.0.10',
  port: 8080,
  proxyAuth: 'userId:password', // optional authentication
  sockets: 50 // optional pool size for each http and https
});
```

After the global settings are establish with a call to `initialize`, both `http.request` and the [`request` library](https://npmjs.org/package/request) will use the proxy information.

The module can also use the `http_proxy` environment variable:

```
process.env.http_proxy = 'http://proxy.example.com:3129';
globalTunnel.initialize();
```

Comment: so there is a global mechanism for proxy settings? because that's basically what the env.http_proxy is, no?

Comment: Can username and password be specified in the global tunnel configuration?

Answer (score 7):

You can try my package `node-global-proxy` which work with all node versions and most of http-client (axios, got, superagent, request etc.)

after install by

`npm install node-global-proxy --save`

a global proxy can start by

```js
const proxy = require("node-global-proxy").default;

proxy.setConfig({
  http: "http://localhost:1080",
  https: "https://localhost:1080",
});
proxy.start();

/** Proxy working now! */
```

More information available here: https://github.com/wwwzbwcom/node-global-proxy

Comment: Is this good to retrieve the URLs I visit in my browser?

Comment: `"https://localhost:1080"` yields error. Says must start with `http://`.

Comment: @izogfif facing same issue any solution ?

Comment: @shivshankar It's been a long time ago, but I somehow managed to make it work. According to `package-lock.json`, the working version was `1.0.1`. The working `index.js` has these lines: `const proxy = require("node-global-proxy").default; proxy.setConfig({http: "http://localhost:8888", https: "http://localhost:8888"}); proxy.start();`

Comment: I managed to make it work. unfortunately, it doesn't have any proxy bypass option. so I had to revert back

Comment: @izogfif Change https to http will work. like `https: "http://localhost:1080"`

Comment: @Philip Ehm, that's what I wrote in my comment. Both http and https point to the same address: `http://localhost:8888`

Answer (score 4):

I finally created a module to get this question (partially) resolved. Basically this module rewrites `http.request` function, added the proxy setting then fire. Check my blog post: https://web.archive.org/web/20160110023732/http://blog.shaunxu.me:80/archive/2013/09/05/semi-global-proxy-setting-for-node.js.aspx

Comment: Great solution, I am using a third part middleware, it will make http request, how to resolve proxy issue in this scenario?

Comment: I think the code in my blog can solve your problem if the 3rd party module utilizes `http` module to send request. Just ensure you `require` my module before the 3rd party one.

Comment: Url return 404, I found this one http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2013/09/05/semi-global-proxy-setting-for-node.js.aspx

Answer (score 3):

While not a Nodejs setting, I suggest you use *proxychains* which I find rather convenient. It is probably available in your package manager.

After setting the proxy in the config file (`/etc/proxychains.conf` for me), you can run `proxychains npm start` or `proxychains4 npm start` (i.e. `proxychains [command_to_proxy_transparently]`) and all your requests will be proxied automatically.

***Config settings for me:***

These are the minimal settings you will have to append

```
## Exclude all localhost connections (dbs and stuff)
localnet 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
## Set the proxy type, ip and port here
http    10.4.20.103 8080
```

(You can get the ip of the proxy by using `nslookup [proxyurl]`)

Answer (score -5):

replace *{userid}* and *{password}* with your id and password in your organization or login to your machine.

```
npm config set proxy http://{userid}:{password}@proxyip:8080/
npm config set https-proxy http://{userid}:{password}@proxyip:8080/
npm config set http-proxy http://{userid}:{password}@proxyip:8080/
strict-ssl=false
```

Comment: Note that {userid} and {password} need to be URL-encoded, if they contain meta-characters (like "/", ":", "@", ...)

Comment: This is already addressed in the question. This question is about a node.js proxy, not an npm proxy.