# execute node js command through http proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy

I want to execute "node index.js"  through a http proxy . Inside the js file there are some libraries that make http requests by axios and I need to route all requests through a proxy without changing the libraries.
How can I do it?
(I execute the node command  or pm2 in linux shell)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18586902/1178759)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can help you:
[Node.js global proxy setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586902/node-js-global-proxy-setting)

that means: you should use a module(global-tunnel), and set proxy to that module, then other modules can use proxy.
Hope this help.