# Redirect async calls made by npm module "request" inside a nodejs express app

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to capture an async call made by "request".
The call I am looking to intercept is "https://api.ap.org/v2/yada/yada" .

I want to intercept this third party call to api.ap.org and redirect it to another service, say 127.0.0.1:3001.

I would also like to add headers during this intercept process.

I know how to intercept all calls made by the express js route via http-proxy, but this does not intercept calls made within nodejs itself.

```
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   request("https://api.ap.org/v2/yada/yada", {}, (err, data) => {
       console.log('---- call made')
       console.log(data);
    });
   res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
 });
```

## UPDATE - from Estus

```
function patchedRequest(url, options, ...args) {
  let newUrl = 'https://www.google.com/' // replace url with another one;
  console.log('------ args');
  console.log(url);
  console.log(options);
  if(url.match(/api\.ap\.org/).length){
      options = {};
      newUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api'
  }
  return originalRequest(newUrl, options, ...args);
}
```

- This allows me to intercept the call to the third party API and send it the service of my choosing.

Thanks Estus!

Comment: *this does not intercept calls made within nodejs itself* - what does exactly not work? Is a callback not called?

Comment: Long story short,
I cannot change the code inside this app.
I can only add an external app or add some code to the entry "app.js" file. 
There are thousands of calls made to third party endpoints. I need to redirect all of them but I am using api.ap.org as a starting point.

Comment: You can mock `request`, with `rewire` or something. Or proxy Node requests globally, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586902/node-js-global-proxy-setting . Or specify a proxy just for `request`, https://github.com/request/request#controlling-proxy-behaviour-using-environment-variables . The actual solution depends on how things are done in your case.

Comment: "request" is required thousands of times. Each require is a new instance. I dont think "request" made their module into a singleton. I would have to fork the repo and add a hook into the "request" module and use my fork instead. 
I tried to use nginx as a NON transparent forward proxy and had issues with that as well.

Comment: `request` itself is a singleton. JS modules are singletons by definition. `require('request') === require('request')`. You can create a wrapper with `proxyquire` (I don't think that `rewire` does the job) or else instead of forking `request`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by mocking original `request` module.

This is roughly how cache-mangling libraries like `proxyquire` work:

*patch-request.js*

```
const originalRequest = require('request');

function patchedRequest(url, ...args) {
  const newUrl = 'https://www.google.com/' // replace url with another one;
  return originalRequest(newUrl, ...args);
}

Object.assign(patchedRequest, originalRequest);

for (const verb of 'get,head,options,post,put,patch,del,delete'.split(',')) {
  patchedRequest[verb] = function (url, ...args) {
    const newUrl = 'https://www.google.com/' // replace url with another one;
    return originalRequest[verb](newUrl, ...args);
  };
}

module.exports = require.cache[require.resolve('request')].exports = patchedRequest;
```

*index.js*

```
// patch request before it's required anywhere else
require('./patch-request');

// load the app that uses request
```

Comment: I think your the man!
I tried many different angles and this is the easiest solution. 
- Updated question with your answer

Comment: Nice work... Also this is just for a test harness I am creating. It will not be released to the public or need of securities.

Comment: You're welcome. A proxy server would be probably more flexible and transparent solution, though it requires more things to care about. As for testing, a less hacky way would be to replace `require('request')` with `rewire('request')` in the app if possible, this is what `rewire` is for.

Comment: True, I was given till the end of today to fix this, then I am off to other less green pastures haha.
I have a tech debt story to come back and come up with a cleaner solution. 
Thanks again for your help

Comment: I see. The solution in the answer is ok as regular solution and perfectly ok as quick fix, I guess this fits your needs.

Comment: Correct fix, after speaking with higher minds.
All my endpoints should be in a config file. 
The config file can be swapped out depending on environment variables. 
As for adding headers before the call is made, I would put nginx as a forward proxy.