# HTTPS proxy server on localhost with Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, localhost, http-proxy

I'm trying to achieve something like this using Express.js: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxXkP.png

```
const app = require("https-localhost")()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    // open req.originalUrl in browser
})

app.listen();
```

I have two problems:

1. I get this error from Chrome: `ERR_PROXY_CERTIFICATE_INVALID`
2. I don't know how to make my proxy server open the original URL requested in the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can install apache as a reverse proxy server, read more details in this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension)

Comment: That wouldn't work. I need to get all the URLs I visit in the browser and then execute a script on each one of those. And my script is written in Node.js.

Comment: That mean you are going to read urls history ?

Comment: I need to read every url requested to the browser in real time so that I can send it as an input to my other script. The only solution I could think of to do this was to use a local proxy set into my browser. I want to browse websites like I normally would, all the operations (urls being sent to my other script) should happen in the background without me noticing.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: [Node.js global proxy setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586902/node-js-global-proxy-setting)

that means: you should use a module(global-tunnel), and set proxy to that module, then other modules can use proxy. Hope this help.

Comment: Sorry but I fail to understand how that could help me. After I start the proxy (provided that the code actually works), what should I do to retrieve all the Urls going through it?